# Get process memory information

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to get process memory information in windows, and I've been following Microsoft docs and I've got this code but it 
doesn't seem to work. It is supposed to print succeeded, but it doesn't print anything at all. My debugging tells me its because hProcess = null, 
but i don't understand why. Here is my current code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    for (int i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
    int processID = aProcesses[i];
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID );

    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return 2;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {
        cout<<"SUCCEEDED";
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `<< flush;` or `<< endl;` to the line with `cout` - it probably does print it, just not flushing it out onto the console.

Comment: not the problem the program returns 2

Comment: Your for loop may be returning too early. What if you just skip `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` and `CloseHandle()` if `OpenProcess()` returns 0?

Comment: I agree with Alexey - just because you can't open a process doesn't mean you should stop - just open the next one.

Comment: yeah i got it the problem was that i was breaking out to early i am using a continue statement instead of return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have permission to read memory of certain (privileged system) processes.  Check `GetLastError` if you get a NULL handle back from `OpenProcess`.

In general checking and handling Win32 error conditions is a good practice, even if the API 'usually' works for you.